# Camera stream rotation on the platform level

Tags: camera, android-10, aosp

In the Quectel SC600Y board, I have a camera sensor (OV4188) that is mounted 90°CCW in relation to the device's default screen orientation, therefore, the stream that is displayed is also rotated 90°CCW. On the registry level, the sensor allows only to flip and mirror the stream but it doesn't allow for rotations. I could solve this problem by rotating the preview on the android application level, however, this is quite a performance costly task that I would rather avoid.

Is there a configuration that would allow to rotate the stream on the android platform level? (I believe that it would be less performance costly than rotation on the android application level) Any tips and hints will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if this is on topic. A quick search shows some type of setting for camera rotation in Camera HAL: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/hardware/libhardware/+/master/include/hardware/camera3.h  but also realize that for app developers this is an existing problem: https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/orientation-rotation

Comment: Note that development-related issue is off-topic since Android Enthusiasts focuses on end-users or power-users (but not necessarily developers) solving their issues. This might be a borderline topic though, depending on the meaning of "configuration" on this question (we can only answer on the Android OS level, not the development board).